# Make use of SOME native SIP classes with SipManager not supported

Tags: android, sip, rtp

I started to develop an android VoIP client based on MjSip. I have found myself rewriting SIP APIs as the ones in MjSip are a mess or not working properly ! So I want to take a shortcut by using some native SIP classes like : SipProfile, SipProfile.Builder, SipErrorCode, SipSession.State...
Is it possible to bypass the isApiSupported() and isVoipSupported() and profit from the classes that does not generate/receive (S)IP traffic ? (classes other than SipManager/SipAudioCall/SipSession)

And how come RTP was only introduced in API 12 and yet SIP is available since API 9, which protocol/RTP implementation were used before RTP support ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, why not simply use [PjSip](http://www.pjsip.org/%20PjSIP)? It is a widely used library with a lot of open source code using it.

For the second part, the RTP stack was probably used along with the SIP API since the beginning. It was simply not publicly available until API 12.

Comment: is it possible to use those RTP "hidden" classes (got their source code) in API 9 ? I am looking for an RTP API here and not PjSIP, I don't want to "attack" NDK/JNI right now!